# How to build a function with arguments listed as a string vector in R?

Tags: r, functional-programming, nse

How might I write a function that takes a string vector and returns a function with arguments having the names of the string vector? In addition, I'd like to use my string of arguments to make a `list` or `data.frame` named with the input columns inside that function. My desired application is to be able to pass this to a `predict` method for estimating some points. If this function already exists, let me know. Otherwise, I'm curious how I might write it. Below I include R pseudo-code illustrating what I am trying to do and hopefully showing where I getting stuck conceptually.

```
make_fitting_function <- function(mod) {
   x <- xterms(mod)
   function(!! x) {
     predict(mod, newdata = list(!! x))
   }
}
```

Calling this function returns a function that can be called on separate vector arguments. For example:

```
f <- make_fitting_function(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars))
f(wt = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

The result would be:

```
    1     2     3     4     5 
31.94 26.60 21.25 15.91 10.56
```

However, this would also work for many more x variables (e.g.):

```
f <- make_fitting_function(lm(mpg ~ wt + am + carb, data = mtcars))
f(wt = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), am = rep(1, 5), carb = seq(2, 10, by = 2))
```

Ideally, this function should be able to be used by integrate in the case of a single variable.

Comment: So how exactly would you call this function and what would the desired output be? A more concrete [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Also are you looking specifically for this to work with dplyr 0.6? Because that notation isn't part of base R at all.

Comment: Yeah, I made the notation up (remembering the dplyr 0.6 syntax) because I wasn't sure how to build the function with the desired arguments. I am looking for calling this function not on a matrix, but on separate vectors for each argument (that gets combined into a matrix for predict). I would call this from inside of a dplyr pipeline though.

Comment: Well since those operators aren't exactly standard yet, it would be better to be more explicit about exactly what you mean. Just give an example of calling a function and giving the result (you can leave off the implementation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need to name the parameters; instead just make the data frame to pass in to predict using all of them.

```
make_fitting_function <- function(model) {
    function(...) {
        predict(model, newdata=data.frame(...))
    }
}
f <- make_fitting_function(lm(mpg ~ wt + am + carb, data = mtcars))
f(wt = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), am = rep(1, 5), carb = seq(2, 10, by = 2))
##         1         2         3         4         5 
## 30.589985 24.637415 18.684846 12.732277  6.779708
```

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my issue. The trouble with this approach, is that I can't seem to be able to call the arguments positionally. That seems to be preventing me from calling it from the `integrate` function.

Comment: Perhaps post as a new question with more details?